# Is the any solution to setup permissions folders linux for a NFS disk [GCP filestore]?

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, permissions, nfs

Currently, the only access control provided by GCP is by Restrict access by IP address or range.

I'm looking for something more granular at the folders level.

All the VMs have most of the users with sudo privileges of course setup a local group would not accomplice this problem.

Looking for external AD or something already embedded with GCP?

How to mount NFS : https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/mounting-fileshares?_ga=2.25001082.-1180806314.1641571641